# In a WPF, how do I check if conditions are met everytime something is ticked or written?

Tags: c#, wpf

Basically, I took a crack at making a puzzle game / solve the code for extra credit at uni. But right now, it seems that the way I did it (because of lack on how else) is sluggish and definetly not recommended.

I'd like for it to check wether or not the conditions are met everytime they tick a checkbox or enter something in a textbox.

```
//the conditions
if ((txbName.Text == "Tim") && (txbFamName.Text == "Dams") &&    (txbLocation.Text == "AP") && (txbPassword.Text == "C#") && (cbxThird.IsChecked == true) && (cbxA.IsChecked == true) && (cbxApple.IsChecked == true))
            MessageBox.Show("You solved the puzzle!");
```

Here is my XAML file

https://gist.github.com/themaawaa/70f11afa6a791c0f49f0

Here is my code

https://gist.github.com/themaawaa/4703a7a4a06e4787ef16

Comment: You sure went to a lot of effort to make your checkboxes behave exactly like radio buttons

Comment: I recommend you have your checkboxes reuse their handlers. For example, instead of cbxFirst_Checked, just have a OnCheckboxChecked handler used by all of them. Check the sender object to see which one it was. Put the checkboxes in a datastructure to make this easier, and allow you to use loops to shorten the code. Then you will have less code repetition when calling a method to check the conditions.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I've never used radiobuttons. Not sure what they do.

Comment: @KhyadHalda Sorry. I only started c# 2 weeks ago and this is very confusing to me. Have you got any visual representation of this?

Comment: @KhyadHalda I think a better approach is to use a binding.  And for event handlers, just define a handler on a surrounding Grid or StackPanel and let event bubbling to to work for ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having dozens of Click events, try using Data Binding which is what WPF was made for. This way you can Bind your checkboxes to bool properties and actually decrese complexity of both code and view, also: radio buttons

```
<TextBox Name="txtbx1" Text="{Binding TextBoxPropertyName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" />
```

and in code behind you have:

```
private string _textBoxPropertyName;
public string TextBoxPropertyName {
    /*your get and set logic here*/
    get{return _textBoxPropertyName;} 
    set{CheckForWinCondition(); _textBoxPropertyName = value;}
}
```

Comment: So where exactly do I put that in those 2 examples? I've never used data binding and I'm a bit confused

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/hello-bound-world/

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. Like this then?

<TextBox Name="txbName" Text="{Binding txbName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150" />